# Cucumber hooks are being run, but not the tests

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm getting the error: `cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class steps.MyStepdefs`

Here's what I'm trying to do.  My hooks are located in the package `steps`:

```java
public class hooks {
    public static WebDriver webDriver;

    @Before
    public static void ChromeDriverSetup() {

        System.out.println("Creating new ChromeDriver instance...");
        webDriver = new ChromeDriver();

        System.out.println("Hello from hooks!");
    }
```

The above is executed...

But the `MyStepdefs` test class does not execute (it is also in the `steps` package) & I get the above error.

```
public class MyStepdefs {
   ProductPage productPageObjects = new ProductPage();


    @Given("I purchase {int} items of the same product")
    public void iPurchaseItemsOfTheSameProduct(int qty)  {

        System.out.println("Hello from MySteps!");
        productPageObjects.Visit();
        productPageObjects.ClickPlusQtyElement(qty);
    }
```

```
package pageobjects;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import static steps.hooks.webDriver;

public class ProductPage {

    private WebElement totalQtyElement = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sanitized"));
    private WebElement plusQtyElement = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sanitized"));

    public void Visit() {
        webDriver.get("https://www.example.com");
    }


    public String ClickPlusQtyElement(int qty) {

        int minAmount = 1;
        while (minAmount < qty)
        {
            plusQtyElement.click();
            minAmount ++;

        }
        System.out.println("The amount is now: " + totalQtyElement.getText());

        return totalQtyElement.getText();
    }
}
```

In IntelliJ, my `glue` is set as `steps`.  I also have a `RunCucumberTest` class in the `steps` package.

```
package steps;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags = "not @ignore", plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"})
public class RunCucumberTest {}
```

Why does it not execute `MyStepsdefs` ?

stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/X5KhHfuP

*Update*:  When I comment out calls to `ProductPage`  the line `System.out.println("Hello from MySteps!");` does get executed.  So there is an issue with that particular call.

Comment: what's the full stack trace? Failed to init is the deepest error msg?

Comment: added stacktrace

Comment: @CodeRocker U have a NPE -- Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pageobjects.ProductPage.<init>(ProductPage.java:16)
    at steps.MyStepdefs.<init>(MyStepdefs.java:15).

Comment: @CodeRocker No need for the hooks to be static. Is it a cucumber Before or junit?

Comment: It's Cucumber Before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.  When I try to instantiate the class `ProductPage`, I get an error due to the web driver calls  i.e. `private WebElement totalQtyElement = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sanitized"));`

The problem is that I haven't visited a URL yet!  So, I am going to put the above in a method and do some refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

If you analyse the stacktrace then we see **NullPointerException** being occurred at 16 line with in Class **ProductPage.java**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pageobjects.ProductPage.<init>(ProductPage.java:16)
    at steps.MyStepdefs.<init>(MyStepdefs.java:15)
    ... 18 more
```

Please check the initialization at the above line as probably that reference is being used in below code at line **productPageObjects.Visit();**

```
public class MyStepdefs {

    @Given("I purchase {int} items of the same product")
    public void iPurchaseItemsOfTheSameProduct(int qty)  {

        System.out.println("Hello from MySteps!");
        productPageObjects.Visit();
        productPageObjects.ClickPlusQtyElement(qty);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, yep, I am creating a new instance of  the `ProductPage` class  at the very top! (Now added back).  I don't understand why there is a `NullPointerException` when I am creating a new instance of the class.

Comment: Can you add code of class Product page starting 20 lines at least.

Comment: Can you pass path of step definition in glue option of Cucumberoptions in runner and check.

Comment: `Can you pass path of step definition in glue option`   I've put down 'steps' as that is the package name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your ProductPage. When you are instantiating those 2 web elements fields :

```
private WebElement totalQtyElement = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sanitized"));
private WebElement plusQtyElement = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sanitized"));
```

you get a null pointer exception.

Why? Because at that moment the `@Before` hook hasn't run and your `webDriver` is still null when you are trying to instantiate your ProductPage.

I'd suggest moving all these calls ( `webDriver.findElement` ) inside a step definition or inside a method that is called from a step definition. This way you can be sure that the ordering of the instantiation will not cause you problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Close - it turns out I hadn't visited the URL.  Have posted my answer above!